# Position Edge labels using iGraph

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, graph, igraph

**My Environment**

I am using `iGraph version 0.7.1` and `python 2.7.1` on `windows 2010` platform.

**What's the Problem**
While working with `iGraph` to generate `Bi-Directional` graph , I can control `vertex label` using `vertex_label_dist` attribute.

However, I did not find any attribute to control `edge label` distance. I did try using `edge_label_dist` , which I did not find in any documentation. The code did not through any error , but its not adjusting `edge_labels` from the `edge_line` either.

The `value` of `edges` is getting mixed up as seen in the below diagram. So instead of edge values showing as `4, 12, 10, 6, 2, 8` , They are shown very close to each other giving an illusion of `108 , 42, 612`.

Is `edge_label_dist` a valid `attribute` to control `edge_label` or is there some other method / attribute? What am I missing here?

**Here is my code**

```
from igraph import *
#from cairo import *

gd = Graph(directed = True) # initialize graph
gd.add_vertices(3) #Add 3 vertices
gd.add_edges([(0,1),(1,2),(0, 2),(2,1),(1,0),(2,0)]) # Add edges
gd.vs["names"] = ["A", "B", "C"]    #Label Vertices
gd.es["weights"] = [4, 12, 10, 6, 2, 8] #Label Edges

#Layout and plot graph
layout = gd.layout("kk")    
gd.vs["label"] = gd.vs["names"]
gd.es["label"] = gd.es["weights"]
plot(gd, layout = layout, vertex_color = "green",
     bbox = (400, 400), edge_label_dist = 3,margin = 60)
```

**Bi-Directional Graph Plot**

[image: Bi Directional Graph]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the [part of the code](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/igraph/drawing/edge.py#L126) that proposes a position for the label of the edge does not take the curvature of the edge into account - it assumes that the edge is a straight line. You can either patch the function above, or try appending and prepending spaces to the edge labels.

(If you happen to come up with a patch that takes edge curvature into account, please [send us a pull request](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/pulls)).